# How to get access token on the basis of Mobile number and OTP?

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am using identityServer4 in my web application and it's amazing.But now we are creating Mobile application for the same project and in mobile application we want to implement Login functionality on the basis of User's registered mobile and OTP sent to that user. Is there any way to implement that functionality in IdentityServer4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Since IDS4 doesn't dictate any particular authentication mechanism you can implement an authentication UI flow you like. Can you explain your desired user experience a bit more?

Comment: I have a question like this if you can answer.tanks.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934055/how-can-i-get-token-from-token-endpoint-without-username-and-password-in-identit