# how can I get token from token endpoint without username and password in identityserver4?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4, access-token

I'm using IdentityServer4 for user authentication and authorization in my asp.net core web api.I use this api in android application.My users Signup and Login with username and password with no problem .And here is my access token that I got from **connect/token endpoint**

```
{
  "alg": "RS512",
  "typ": "at+jwt"
}
{
  "nbf": 1600324303,
  "exp": 1631860303,
  "iss": "https://myIdentityServerApi.com",
  "aud": [
    "IdentityServerApi",
    "MyAPI1"
  ],
  "client_id": "MyApp1",
  "sub": "521d198c-3657-488e-997e-3e50d756b353",
  "auth_time": 1600324302,
  "idp": "local",
  "role": "Admin",
  "name": "myusername",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "IdentityServerApi",
    "MyAPI1"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

Now in my new android application I want users signup and login with phone number and sms activation.
When User send the ActivationCode I should send him access token.But how can I get token from token endpoint without username and password?

In below I wanted to generate token manually.but generated token don't work.

```
        [HttpPost("Activate")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Activate([FromBody] SignUpPhoneModel model)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.PhoneNumber))
            {
                return BadRequest("Phone Number is Empty");
            }

            PhoneValidation pv = new PhoneValidation();


            IdentityUser CurrentUser = await db.Users.Where(e => e.PhoneNumber == model.PhoneNumber).FirstAsync();
            if (!await UserManager.VerifyChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync(CurrentUser, model.ActivationCode, model.PhoneNumber))
            {
                return BadRequest("Activation Code is not correct");
            }
            else
            {
                //Here user is activated and should get token But How?
                CurrentUser.PhoneNumberConfirmed = true;
                List<string> UserRoles = (await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(CurrentUser)).ToList();
                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

                RSACryptoServiceProvider rsap = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(KeyContainerNameForSigning);
                SecurityKey sk = new RsaSecurityKey(rsap.Engine);
                List<Claim> UserClaims = new List<Claim>() {
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, CurrentUser.Id),

                };
                foreach (var r in UserRoles)
                {
                    UserClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, r));
                }
                var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
                     Issuer= "https://myidentityserverapi.com",
                    Audience = "IdentityServerApi,MyAPI",
                     
                    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(UserClaims),
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(365),
                    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(sk, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha512),
                };
                var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
                TokenModel tm = new TokenModel()
                {
                    access_token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token)
                };
                return Ok(tm);
            }
        }
```

When I recieve token from above(actionvation method) in my application is like below,But It don't work for example `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false.Does any one know How can I generate token like connect/token endpoint without username and password?

```
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}

{
  "unique_name": "13f2e130-e2e6-48c7-b3ac-40f8dde8087b",
  "role": "Member",
  "nbf": 1600323833,
  "exp": 1718259833,
  "iat": 1600323833
}
```

Did I choose the right method? Or I should use another way for example different flow or grant types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally create access token like this:

```
[HttpPost("Activate")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Activate([FromBody] SignUpPhoneModel model, [FromServices] ITokenService TS, [FromServices] IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<JooyaIdentityUser> principalFactory, [FromServices] IdentityServerOptions options)
        {           
            JooyaIdentityUser CurrentUser = await db.Users.Where(e => e.PhoneNumber == model.PhoneNumber).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            
            if (!await UserManager.VerifyChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync(CurrentUser, model.ActivationCode, model.PhoneNumber))
            {
                return BadRequest("Activation Code in not correct");
            }
            CurrentUser.PhoneNumberConfirmed = true;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(CurrentUser);
            var Request = new TokenCreationRequest();
            var IdentityPricipal = await principalFactory.CreateAsync(CurrentUser);
            var IdentityUser = new IdentityServerUser(CurrentUser.Id.ToString());
            IdentityUser.AdditionalClaims = IdentityPricipal.Claims.ToArray();
            IdentityUser.DisplayName = CurrentUser.UserName;
            IdentityUser.AuthenticationTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
            IdentityUser.IdentityProvider = IdentityServerConstants.LocalIdentityProvider;
            Request.Subject = IdentityUser.CreatePrincipal();
            Request.IncludeAllIdentityClaims = true;
            Request.ValidatedRequest = new ValidatedRequest();
            Request.ValidatedRequest.Subject = Request.Subject;

            Request.ValidatedRequest.SetClient(SeedConfig.GetClients().Where(e => e.ClientId == model.ClientId).First());
            List<ApiResource> Apis = new List<ApiResource>();
            Apis.Add(SeedConfig.GetApis().Where(e => e.Name == "IdentityServerApi").First());
            Apis.Add(SeedConfig.GetApis().Where(e => e.Name == model.ApiName).First());
            Request.Resources = new Resources(SeedConfig.GetIdentityResources(), Apis);
            Request.ValidatedRequest.Options = options;
            Request.ValidatedRequest.ClientClaims = IdentityUser.AdditionalClaims;
            var Token = await TS.CreateAccessTokenAsync(Request);
            Token.Issuer = HttpContext.Request.Scheme + "://" + HttpContext.Request.Host.Value;
            Token.Lifetime = 32000000;
            var TokenValue = await TS.CreateSecurityTokenAsync(Token);
            TokenModel tm = new TokenModel()
            {
                access_token = TokenValue
            };
            return Ok(tm);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that your users activate their `ActivationCode` through IS4 server. If that's the case, you don't need to manage/generate mannually your `access_token`.

You have just to follow the same procedure that the `Login` method inside the AccountController, consisting to:

1. Check user with login/password, in your case validate your `ActivationCode`
2. Once user identified, `SignIn` your user by SignInManager. ([SignInManager.SignInAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.signinasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1))
3. Raise UserLoginSuccessEvent event.

   `await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.UserName, user.Id, user.UserName, clientId: context?.Client.ClientId));`
4. Finally redirect user to your web app.

   `return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);`

When redirecting to your application, IdentityServer4 will send to the user its `access_token`.

Comment: I want to use your answer in my web api .what should I do with Redirect?

Comment: I have an android application so I should return token to user after activation.My users recieve token with sms and send it to above method.then user is activated ,then they should get token.But How can I generate token?Should I get the token from connect/token? but how when I don't have username and password

Comment: No need to generate token, it's your action, when redirecting to your redirectUrl, will send to your app the token.
For android app, just use deep link to redirect to your app, then retrieve the token from parameter.

Comment: I don't know how use this in my asp.net core web api that have identityserver4.do you have any tutorile

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to do is that when the user confirms the activation code you do the same things as covered in the:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model, string button) { }
```

As found in the reference AccountController.cs class.

Comment: Above method or activation method is login method.but the generated token don't work.i want to know how connect/token is generating token and then to generate token

Comment: think its hard to generate your own tokens,better to signin the user by "faking" a login using the logic in the Login method above... Better to always follow the official flows and approaches than trying to hack your own solution. Authenticating with login/password is never a requirement, you can tweak the code in the account or ExternalController, that is just how i would do it.

Comment: I have an asp.net core web api.How can I signin.I think I should return the token.How can I find token?

Comment: what do you want to sign in? Do you want to sign in a user or application to access your API? Based on that you either use the authorization code flow or client credentials flow. Regardles of what, you use the AddOpenIdConnect authentication handler to get the token from IdentityServe

Comment: I want to sign in a user so I think I should use the authorization code flow .but I don't see good example and tutorial of how can I implemnet this .do you know a tutorial or example?