# TokenCreationRequest does not contain a definition for Resources

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt, identityserver4

I had a question for creating token without username and password here [how can I get token from token endpoint without username and password in identityserver4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934055/how-can-i-get-token-from-token-endpoint-without-username-and-password-in-identit)

But recently I decided to update my projects to use  .net5 ,but after that I found that my host don't support .net5 so I removed All .net5 and Installed the versions to 3.1.But below error is there I don't know how solve it

```
Error   CS1061  'TokenCreationRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Resources' and no accessible extension method 'Resources' accepting a first argument of type 'TokenCreationRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'apiScopes' of 'Resources.Resources(IEnumerable<IdentityResource>, IEnumerable<ApiResource>, IEnumerable<ApiScope>)'
```

My code:

```
[HttpPost("Activate")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Activate([FromBody] SignUpPhoneModel model, [FromServices] ITokenService TS, [FromServices] IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<JooyaIdentityUser> principalFactory, [FromServices] IdentityServerOptions options)
        {           
            JooyaIdentityUser CurrentUser = await db.Users.Where(e => e.PhoneNumber == model.PhoneNumber).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            
            if (!await UserManager.VerifyChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync(CurrentUser, model.ActivationCode, model.PhoneNumber))
            {
                return BadRequest("Activation Code in not correct");
            }
            CurrentUser.PhoneNumberConfirmed = true;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(CurrentUser);
            var Request = new TokenCreationRequest();
            var IdentityPricipal = await principalFactory.CreateAsync(CurrentUser);
            var IdentityUser = new IdentityServerUser(CurrentUser.Id.ToString());
            IdentityUser.AdditionalClaims = IdentityPricipal.Claims.ToArray();
            IdentityUser.DisplayName = CurrentUser.UserName;
            IdentityUser.AuthenticationTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
            IdentityUser.IdentityProvider = IdentityServerConstants.LocalIdentityProvider;
            Request.Subject = IdentityUser.CreatePrincipal();
            Request.IncludeAllIdentityClaims = true;
            Request.ValidatedRequest = new ValidatedRequest();
            Request.ValidatedRequest.Subject = Request.Subject;

            Request.ValidatedRequest.SetClient(SeedConfig.GetClients().Where(e => e.ClientId == model.ClientId).First());
            List<ApiResource> Apis = new List<ApiResource>();
            Apis.Add(SeedConfig.GetApis().Where(e => e.Name == "IdentityServerApi").First());
            Apis.Add(SeedConfig.GetApis().Where(e => e.Name == model.ApiName).First());
            Request.Resources = new Resources(SeedConfig.GetIdentityResources(), Apis);// <=== Error is here
            Request.ValidatedRequest.Options = options;
            Request.ValidatedRequest.ClientClaims = IdentityUser.AdditionalClaims;
            var Token = await TS.CreateAccessTokenAsync(Request);
            Token.Issuer = HttpContext.Request.Scheme + "://" + HttpContext.Request.Host.Value;
            Token.Lifetime = 32000000;
            var TokenValue = await TS.CreateSecurityTokenAsync(Token);
            TokenModel tm = new TokenModel()
            {
                access_token = TokenValue
            };
            return Ok(tm);
        }
```

Comment: How exactly did you adjust your code? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a versión of IdentityServer4 that is not compatible with your code. The model of `TokenCreationRequest` has changed. Last version of IdentityServer4 (4.1.1) hasn't the `Resources` property. It uses `ValidatedResources` of type `ResourceValidationResult` instead.

You need to adjust your code or downgrade to an older version of IdentityServer < 4.0.0.